# COGNOS - XQE-JDB-0004 A pr0blem occurred finding the driver class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, cognos

I'm on a Windows 8 machine and attempting to connect IBM's COGNOS BI (I'm using the trial version - it's on the cloud) to MySQL, upon setting up the connection COGNOS always feed back

> XQE-JDB-0004 A problem occurred finding the driver class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".

I have added a system variable that specifies CLASSPATH and the full path to *mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar*; however, I'm unsure if the software, being on the cloud, would even be capable of finding my CLASSPATH. This error seems like nonsense to me.

Is COGNOS broken, or am I missing a step?

Comment: A lot of Java applications don't use the `CLASSPATH` environment variables. Have you checked how Cognos needs to be configured, or where you need to put libraries?

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the Cognos server that you are connecting to has not yet been configured to connect to a MySQL instance. Cognos 10.2.2.2 and later supports MySQL in Dynamic Query Mode via JDBC and MySQL in Compatible Query Mode via ODBC but both of these require some configuration on the server(s) running the reporting services before it will work.

[This section](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.dyn_query.10.2.2.doc/t_dqm_conn_jdbc.html) of the 10.2.2.2 manual indicates the steps that would be required to reconfigure the BI server to use your .jar file - however that's not possible if you can't access the server itself, so you may be better off looking into obtaining and configuring a locally hosted trial instance.